# RXJs Angular - object undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I will preface this with the knowledge I am VERY new to angular, as in I am trying to get simple things to work and struggling greatly!

I have a simple WebAPI that will return a JSON array containing three objects:

URL: https://localhost:44397/api/account

#### testListType.ts

```
export interface listTypes {
    limitTypeId: number;
    limitTypeText: string;
    limitTypeActive: boolean;
}
```

I then load rxjs up unto a service

#### test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { listTypes } from '../models/testListType';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {


  getlistTypes(): Observable<listTypes[]> {
    var returnable = this.http.get<listTypes[]>('https://localhost:44397/api/account');
    return returnable;
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

And finally try and display the content of that return on a component

#### testing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { listTypes } from '../models/testListType';
import { TestService } from '../services/test.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testing.component.css']
})
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {

  lists: listTypes[] = [];

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getListTypes();
  }

  getListTypes(): void {
    this.testService.getlistTypes()
        .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists);
  }

}
```

This is the result of modifying the Hero's of Ages tutorial on Angular to fit my requirements. Unfortunately it displays nothing and I am too novice to understand how to debug the subscribe method (I have attempted and get a non-sensical object).

All I can see in the debugger when I try to access lists is the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lists is not defined

No doubt there is a fundamental I have missed and I expect a angular expert will see it in seconds, but I have been staring at this for 2 hours now!

Any assistance would be great.

UPDATE - Added component html

#### testing.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="testService.listTypes.length">

    <h2>Test</h2>
    <div *ngFor='let lists of testService.listTypes'> {{listTypes}} </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Share the template code (the html) where you are using the `lists` from the component.

Comment: @atiyar template added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the template code to -

```html
<div *ngIf = "lists.length>0">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of lists"> {{ item }} </div>  
</div>
```

Its the component's responsibility to gather data which would be displayed through the template. You have already done that in the `getListTypes()` by calling the service method which populated the `lists` array with data returned by the service.

The template's responsibility is to display the data gathered by the component. With the `*ngFor="let item of lists"` statement, you just enumerate over the already populated `lists` array from the component, and display each item. You shouldn't call services from the template code.